# How to find if a graph contains a cycle using a recursive DFS?

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-theory

The code below is an implementation of a depth-first
 search DFS to determine if a directed graph has a cycle or not. However, there appears to be a bug in it as it's not working. I'm almost 100% sure that the bug lies in `if (visited[w])` condition. My logic here is basically - if a node has already been visited, then a cycle exists. However, the problem with `if (visited[w])` is that although the condition may be true, it doesn't necessarily mean that there is a cycle, as the node may have been visited long ago.

```
int *visited;  // array [0..V-1] of booleans

int checkCycle(Graph g)
{
   visited = malloc(sizeof(int)*g->numVertices);
   int result = dfsCycleCheck(g, 0);
   free(visited);
   return result;
}
int dfsCycleCheck(Graph g, Vertex v)
{
   visited[v] = 1;
   Vertex w;
   for (w = 0; w < nV(g); w++) {
      if (!hasEdge(g,v,w)) continue;
      if (visited[w]) return 1; // found cycle
      return dfsCycleCheck(g, w);
   }
   return 0; // no cycle
}
```

Comment: `malloc()` does not initialize the memory it provides to you, and you do not initialize it yourself.  Who knows what's in it?  If you want it to start as all-zero then the easiest solution is to allocate with `calloc()` instead of with `malloc()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I initialised everything to 0 using a for loop (not shown above), but that's not the issue apparently

Comment: Also, you do a DFS starting at node 0, but if your graph is not connected then you can miss a cycle that is unreachable from that node.

Comment: It's unclear whether your graph has directed edges, but if so, then that, too, will factor in, making it both more likely that you miss a cycle because of the starting node you choose, and trickier to fix that problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The graph is always connected (i.e. all nodes are reachable - no isolated ones). As for directed/undirected, I'd say it'd be a directed graph, but a solution for undirected is also fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there is no way to tell if the visited node has already been visited or if was visited as part of current traversal.

One approach would be to maintain a array of vertices that can hold three states instead of the two which we already have.

> WHITE : Vertex is not processed yet.  Initially
>           all vertices are WHITE.
>
> GRAY : Vertex is being processed (DFS for this 
>          vertex has started, but not finished which means
>          that all descendants (ind DFS tree) of this vertex
>          are not processed yet (or this vertex is in function
>          call stack)
>
> BLACK : Vertex and all its descendants are 
>           processed.
>
> While doing DFS, if we encounter an edge from current  vertex to a
>   GRAY vertex, then this edge is back edge  and hence there is a cycle.

And the code will be something like this.

> ```
> // Recursive function to find if there is back edge
> // in DFS subtree tree rooted with 'u'
> bool Graph::DFSUtil(int u, int color[])
> {
>     // GRAY :  This vertex is being processed (DFS
>     //         for this vertex has started, but not
>     //         ended (or this vertex is in function
>     //         call stack)
>     color[u] = GRAY;
>
>     // Iterate through all adjacent vertices
>     list<int>::iterator i;
>     for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
>     {
>         int v = *i;  // An adjacent of u
>
>         // If there is
>         if (color[v] == GRAY)
>           return true;
>
>         // If v is not processed and there is a back
>         // edge in subtree rooted with v
>         if (color[v] == WHITE && DFSUtil(v, color))
>           return true;
>     }
>
>     // Mark this vertex as processed
>     color[u] = BLACK;
>
>     return false;
> }
>
> // Returns true if there is a cycle in graph
> bool Graph::isCyclic()
> {
>     // Initialize color of all vertices as WHITE
>     int *color = new int[V];
>     for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
>         color[i] = WHITE;
>
>     // Do a DFS traversal beginning with all
>     // vertices
>     for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
>         if (color[i] == WHITE)
>            if (DFSUtil(i, color) == true)
>               return true;
>
>     return false;
> }
> ```

The main difference here is that a node can be visited and still be either black(indicating that the node was visited earlier) or grey(indicating the the node was visited as part of current traversal; so it's a back edge) helping us find out if we have a  cycle or not.

Which was earlier not possible because of a Boolean array we had not distinguishing between the two types of visited nodes.

[Source](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-direct-graph-using-colors/)